# firebase-collection polymer Observers

Tags: firebase, polymer

How can I get notifications about new items added to firebase?

There is no docs for this in firebase-element...
I try to use `observers: [customListner(items.*)]` in the data property but it doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo here, but did you try using "observers" all in lower case?

Comment: Maybe add more code in your question ? It's gonna be hard to help you with so few information. You might want to take a look at this nice example of a Todo list app bound to firebase : https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give an example of how using firebase-collection to listen to an update of collection event? Changes in children or adding a new item?